# linq paging - get total rows

Tags: c#, .net, linq, paging

i have a question about linq. I'm using Skip and Take to do paging:

```
(from l in db.ProductList
          select l).Skip((page - 1) * row_per_page).Take(row_per_page)
```

It work, and i need retrieve total rows of product list to calculate max page. I think i must use another query to count rows but have another way to do this in one query above?

Answer (score 4):

To get a count of the rows, use the .Count() extension method

```
var count = (from l in db.ProductList select l).Count();
```

Comment: or: var count = db.ProductList.Count()

Comment: This will do it, and since it is calling count, it will not have to pull any data pages into memory as this information is kept in the index (assuming this table has at least one); meaning this query will be extremely fast, much faster even than returning a single record.

Answer (score 1):

The bottom line is you will have to enumerate all items to get the total page number. But you would like to enumerate them only once.
I suggest you try GroupBy method to get a IEnumerable> "pages". Then you can use pages.Count() to get page count. Or you can enumerate pages to get each page of items. The GroupBy query will be only executed once.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to get both the total number of rows and a "skip/take" subset of those rows in the same query.

Is there a reason that you need this in two queries?